# How to change DNS when VPN is down?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, vpn, dns, batch

My `DNS` are on the other side of my `VPN` (operator peering). So web is unreachable if the `VPN` is down.

I need to change the DNS on each computers to public `DNS` (150 Windows computers from `XP-SP1` to `Win10`).

How can I script DNS edition ?

Comment: is an operator Peering, not a simple VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this script to Test my DNS over VPN and set local DNS

```
@echo off
ping 192.168.0.252 -n 1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
:: DNS perso
    set DNS1=192.168.0.253
    set DNS2=192.168.0.252
    ) else (
:: Google DNS
    set DNS1=8.8.8.8
    set DNS2=8.8.4.4
    )
for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%i in ('netsh int show interface') do (
        echo Changing "%%l" : %DNS1% + %DNS2%
        netsh int ipv4 set dns name="%%l" static %DNS1% primary validate=no
        netsh int ipv4 add dns name="%%l" %DNS2% index=2 validate=no
)
ipconfig /flushdns
:EOF
```